# Deserialize XML string to bindable object

Tags: c#, xaml

I have access to an XML array of the following format:

```
<Title>Blah</Title>
<Status>Blah</Status>
<Info>
    <Item>Blah blah blah</Item>
    <Item>Blah blah blah</Item>
    ....
</Info>
```

My `MainWindow` sets its `DataContext` to my `MainWindowViewModel` which contains an object `ObservableResults`. This class is `ObservableResults : ObservableCollection<ViewableResult>` and creates a `ViewableResult` object. It also sets this object's member data, `Title, Status, and Info` by parsing the XML string above. I can already bind to this object and display `Title, Status, and Info` as plain text, but need to parse the `Info` node into an additional member of `ViewableResult` or perhaps replace the `Info` member. This would be some kind of object with which I can manipulate each separate `Item` node in the XAML, hopefully to create some kind of custom display format other than just plain text.

Edit: Apparently it's unclear what the question is. I'm trying to find a good method of parsing the `Info` node into an object that can individually access `Item` nodes.

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. Please do so now.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `ViewableResult` object?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I thought it was fairly clear that I was looking for a method of parsing the `Info` node into some kind of object I can manipulate on the `Item` level in my XAML. I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

A good start to solve your problem should be to use Serialization, it's really handy when you need to save Objects into an XML file and load them back for whatever you want.

You should make your objects as serializable then add some methods like Load(), Save(), etc.

Read this for more informations : [MSDN - Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0.aspx)

You'll find plenty informations on how to do this !

Hope it will help.